# HTTP 403 Forbidden error in Spring Web Security

Tags: spring-security

I am attempting to access a controller defined as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/central-cloud-connector/api/v1/connector/version", produces = "application/json")
```

But am getting a 403 error as follows:

```
{
"timestamp": "2023-04-16T18:27:13.550+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"path": "/central-cloud-connector/api/v1/connector/version"
}
```

The controller definition is as follows:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/central-cloud-connector/api/v1/connector/version", produces = "application/json")
    public String getVersion() {
  // Body of the method    
}
```

What we are trying to do is to access the controller without the mandatory security kicking in. This is primarily for testing in local environments.

The Spring Security dependencies used in the project are:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.8.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.8.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.8.2'
```

and the SecurityConfiguration class is

```
    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .securityMatcher("/central-cloud-connector/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .cors().disable()
                    .csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```

Snippets of the application log with Spring Security enabled

```
    Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
Request requested invalid session id 00212494548EA206FE728C5ED4BB5E57
Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@42a59089] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@635ed42a
Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
```

We have tried providing

```
security.basic.enable= false   
management.security.enabled= false
```

as well.
Any suggestions on what is amiss would be very helpful.

Comment: Please add the controller method with annotations that serves the path giving 403

Comment: i dont get what your problem is? `The use case here is quite simply a pass through controller for testing purposes etc` what does this sentance mean? what is a _pass through controller_

Comment: @Toerktumlare
Thanks a lot for the revert. What we are trying to do is test the controller locally without the security checks kicking in, I have edited the original question. Does this help?

Comment: i would not disable security during testing, then the test wont actually test what it is you need to test under the right conditions. Why not just use the built in testing tools that come with spring security?

Answer (score 0):

To test secured endpoints in a local environment without the mandatory security kicking in, you can use the `@WebMvcTest` annotation with the `controllers` parameter set to the controller you want to test. In addition, you can use the `@WithMockUser` annotation to create a mock user with a username and password.

For example, let's say you have a `HelloController` that has a secured endpoint at `/hello` that requires authentication. You can use the code snippet provided to create a test case in your test class. The `testHello()` method sends a GET request to `/hello` using the MockMvc instance and expects the response to contain the string "Hello!".

By using `@WithMockUser`, you can bypass the security requirements and authenticate the mock user instead. This allows you to test the endpoint without triggering the mandatory security measures.

Here is an example

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HelloController.class)
@WithMockUser(username = "alice", password = "12345")
class HelloTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Test
    void testHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/hello"))
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello!"));
    }
}
```